# How to make a view specific to only 1 node, not all nodes

Tags: views, users

I am building a register event calendar so people can sign up for future events. I have the calendar and the registration for events already completed. Now all I want to do is create a view that will display all the current registered users for the event, but here is the problem i'm running into.

In drupal views it is listing ALL the register users for ALL events. So instead of viewing only a group for one specific event, its adding every single person that has ever clicked the register button.

What steps do I have to go through to say "no, only list register users for THIS event"?

My content type is "Date" for setting a event and my registration is set to "Meetings". I'm not quite sure how to tell views to organize each event separately, rather than together.

Comment: Never used the calendar module, but the solution is probably one of these: Add a FILTER of event **or** Add RELANTIONSHIP of event (under advanced), **or** a CONTEXTUAL FILTER of event or node (under advanced)

Comment: Hi shawn have you tried using eva https://www.drupal.org/project/eva you can attached views in any entity even on your node and just configure the contextual filter it also has additional settings if I am not mistaken it is entitity content settings it has additional arguments on it, I am only using phone, but will try to send you some screenshots later

Comment: OP, how are users registering? I can't see it specifically in your post.

Comment: All the answers seem to agree on one point: you need to filter on the discriminating field. Pass that field (or something related to it like the nid) to your view, and your view wll then need to be displayed on a page where that context exists. If you wish to display it elsewhere you will need to find that context and probably use some module more flexible in passing context like Panels.

Answer (score 0):

At Taxonomy add one vocabulary and name as "Event". At content type add fields for particular info and "Event". User will fill up the particular as well as event type. At views filter by Event category. This is an example and I not really what is your structure. Hope it help